# First time trying to create a DLL with a lot of classes, bundled in one

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I would like to create one DLL with Visual Studio 2015. I created a project for that. I started to add classes and now I have over a thousand errors on compilation. It looks like I'm having conflicts with low-level C type and C++ itself?

Here is the code : https://github.com/Lorac/GrimDawnCharacterTrainer

```
characterbio.h(6): error C3646: 'level': unknown override specifier (compiling source file src\CharacterBio.cpp)
characterbio.h(6): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (compiling source file src\CharacterBio.cpp)
characterbio.h(7): error C3646: 'experience': unknown override specifier (compiling source file src\CharacterBio.cpp)
characterbio.h(7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (compiling source file src\CharacterBio.cpp)
characterbio.h(8): error C3646: 'modifierPoints': unknown override specifier (compiling source file src\CharacterBio.cpp)
```

I'm using the precompiled headers, should I? I could use some directions on how it would be possible to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your include directives are not right.

**CharacterBio.h**

```
#pragma once

class CharacterBio
{
public:
    uint32_t level;
    uint32_t experience;
    uint32_t modifierPoints;
    uint32_t skillPoints;
    uint32_t devotionPoints;
    uint32_t totalDevotion;
    float physique;
    float cunning;
    float spirit;
    float health;
    float energy;

    void read(GDCFile *);
    void write(GDCFile *);
};
```

**CharacterBio.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CharacterBio.h"
#include "GDCFile.h"
#include "block.h"
#include <cstdint>

void CharacterBio::read(GDCFile *gdc)
{
// <snip>
```

In **CharacterBio.h** you use types from `<cstdint>`, but you don't include it in that header file. The header file should include everything it uses, or at least have forward declarations for appropriate types.

Even when you include **CharacterBio.h** from **CharacterBio.cpp**, `#include <cstdint>` comes after `#include "CharacterBio.h"`.

---

The appropriate way to write the **CharacterBio.h** file would be:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

class GDCFile;

class CharacterBio
{
public:
    uint32_t level;
    uint32_t experience;
    uint32_t modifierPoints;
    uint32_t skillPoints;
    uint32_t devotionPoints;
    uint32_t totalDevotion;
    float physique;
    float cunning;
    float spirit;
    float health;
    float energy;

    void read(GDCFile *);
    void write(GDCFile *);
};
```

---

The same goes for the rest of your code -- very few header files include anything at all!

Comment: Oh I see, amazing! If I look at the GDCFile.h, do I have to forward declare all the classes in there too?

Comment: In that case, forward declarations will not do, because the classes like `Header` are used by value (as members of the GCDFile class). Forward declarations are fine when you use pointers or references (and do not dereference them).

Comment: What would be the best option, to change them into pointers? or keep it as is it?

Comment: Since they are public members, it probably makes sense to include all the relevant headers, as you probably expect the user of the class to want to work with them.

Comment: It looks like I solved the header problems... but now after I generated the obj files it output this : ```CharacterSkills.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Vector<class Skill>::read(class GDCFile *)" (?read@?$Vector@VSkill@@@@QAEXPAVGDCFile@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CharacterSkills::read(class GDCFile *)" (?read@CharacterSkills@@QAEXPAVGDCFile@@@Z)``` **I think I found it**

Comment: Can you push your current code on github, so I can see what you've got?

Comment: I pushed it with the headers fixed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108682/discussion-between-dan-masek-and-maxime-roussin-belanger).